# Recoger datos Datepicker jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

Tengo este código:

```
<input type="form" class="form-control pickadate" placeholder="Fecha inicio" id="datefilter_inicio" name="datefilter_inicio"/>

<input type="form" class="form-control pickadate" placeholder="Fecha fin" id="datefilter_fin" name="datefilter_fin"/>

<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/ui/tether.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/extensions/moment.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script> 
<script src="{{ URL::asset('js/core/libraries/bootstrap.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/dateTime/moment-with-locales.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/dateTime/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.date.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/picker.time.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="{{ URL::asset('vendors/js/pickers/pickadate/legacy.js')}}" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#datefilter_inicio').click(function(){ alert($(this).pickadate('getDate'))};
</script>
```

Me gustaría saber como recoger los datos del datepicker para pasarselos al controlador en laravel y almacenarlo en la base de datos, lo he intentado con click poniendo un boton, pero como esta dentro de un formulario me gustaria coger esos datos automaticamente en la request.

He probado a añadir esto:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$('#datefilter_inicio').pickadate({
    // Strings and translations
    monthsFull: ['Enero', 'Febrero', 'Marzo', 'Abril', 'Mayo', 'Junio', 'Julio', 'Agosto', 'Septiembre', 'Octubre', 'Noviembre', 'Diciembre'],
    monthsShort: ['Ene', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Abr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Ago', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    weekdaysFull: ['Domingo', 'Lunes', 'Martes', 'Miercoles', 'Jueves', 'Viernes', 'Sabado'],
    weekdaysShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mier', 'Jue', 'Vier', 'Sab'],
    showMonthsShort: undefined,
    showWeekdaysFull: undefined,

    // Buttons
    today: 'Hoy',
    clear: 'Limpiar',
    close: 'Cerrar',

    // Accessibility labels
    labelMonthNext: 'Mes prox',
    labelMonthPrev: 'Mes ant',
    labelMonthSelect: 'Selecciona un mes',
    labelYearSelect: 'Selecciona  un año',

    // Formats
    format: 'd mmmm, yyyy',
});

</script>
```

Pero tampoco me hace caso al traducir los nombres, supuestamente la docu oficial de este plugin es esta: https://amsul.ca/pickadate.js/date/

Pero la verdad que no me funciona.

Una ayudita por favor? Muchas gracias.

Comment: Buenas,
 $('#datefilter_inicio').val()
no te funciona?

Comment: @andrésmatínezrodríguez haciendo un vara de eso, deberia poner imprimirlo en un console.log no? De primeras no, no me devuelve nada en la consola ni de por si ni con console. Gracias por tu pronta respuesta

Comment: no conozco la librería, pero mirando en la documentación, veo que tiene un campo `formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',`. Lo has probado?

Comment: Realmente no, disculpa que no me entere del comentario, pero tampoco me esta haciendo caso al resto de codigo del js. Gracias por tu respuesta.

Comment: Gracias, tu ayuda me ha servido. Ya me funciona si quieres pon respuesta y te la doy por valida